# Get attachment by slug

Tags: wp-query, slug, images

I would like to get an image by specifying a certain slug and then echoing that address in the image src code.

The slug for the image would be "book-site-header"

I've looked through the get_wp_attachment and get_wp_attachment_metadata in the wordpress codex but neither makes mention of the slug. Slugs have to be unique and are saved in the DB so it must be possible to find it based on the slug and then get the related file url.

[image: image of slug area]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An attachment is just a post with the `post_status` = `inherit` and the `post_type` = `attachment`, so can be queried with `WP_Query` or `get_posts`.

Note that slug (`post_name`) **is unique per post type**.

```
$_header = get_posts('post_type=attachment&name=book-site-header&posts_per_page=1&post_status=inherit');
$header = $_header ? array_pop($_header) : null;  
$header_url = $header ? wp_get_attachment_url($header->ID) : '';
```

you can also use the code above to built your own custom fucntion

```
function get_attachment_url_by_slug( $slug ) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'name' => sanitize_title($slug),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
  );
  $_header = get_posts( $args );
  $header = $_header ? array_pop($_header) : null;
  return $header ? wp_get_attachment_url($header->ID) : '';
}
```

and then

```
$header_url = get_attachment_url_by_slug('book-site-header');
```

Comment: I've tried both routes, adding the function into the function file and then calling it with $header_url. This resulted in a server error.

I also tried the first option with get_posts, but this resulted in not loading anything below it. I echoed $header_url.

Comment: There was a typo in both code, just fixed. Try now, it work (tested). @Alexnl

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Thank you very much for your quick help!

I will make sure to send you a copy of the ebook when it comes out, as appreciation. www.thesussexdeal.com

Comment: For newer version of wordpress 5 change `name` to `post_title`

Comment: @0x1gene `name` is still valid query parameter for post **slug**: see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters if you want to query post **title** there's the `title` parameter.